# Problems to convert text file to PDF using iText 7 library

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to convert simple text file, where formatting was done using "blanks" (old mainframe files) into PDF format. I'm using iText 7 library and Java 1.8. In general it works, but the formatting using blanks are not shown in resulting PDF, so the indents are not shown in the PDF.

I'm using COURIER font so the blanks should be the same size than the character.

Here ist the java code I'm using:

```java
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

@WrapToTest
public class Text2Pdf {

    // public static final String DEST = "results/text2pdf.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Check for the mandatory 1st argument -> Source File
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("\nUsage:");
            System.out.println("Text2Pdf AbsolutePath2TextFile");
            System.out.println("\nExample:");
            System.out.println("Text2Pdf C:\\Users\\USER1\\Desktop\\HelloWorld.txt");
            System.out.println(
                    "\nResulting .pdf file (HelloWorld.pdf) will be written to Text2PdfResults directory in the current working directory.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Check if given Source File exist ...
        File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);

        // Get the Source and Destination File Name
        String sourceFileName = sourceFile.getName();
        String destFileName = sourceFileName + ".pdf";
        String destFileNameDir = "Text2PdfResults/" + destFileName;

        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("\nERROR:");
            System.out.println("Given source text file " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist!");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        File destFile = new File(destFileNameDir);
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new Text2Pdf().createPdf(sourceFile, destFileNameDir);
    }

    public void createPdf(File sourceFile, String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        document.setFontSize((float) 8.0);
        document.setLeftMargin((float) 40.0);
        document.setRightMargin((float) 40.0);

        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(sourceFile), "UTF8"));
        String line;
        PdfFont normal = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            document.add(new Paragraph(line).setFont(normal));
        }
        document.close();
        br.close();
    }
```

Here is the plain text file I want to convert:

```
Test Customer                                                         28.06.2019
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         10        20        30        40        50        60        70       79
         This section starts with 10 blanks                      right alignment
---------1. Test Nr. 1
         2. Test Nr. 2         
--------------------
    Section starts with 5 blanks ...
This is the last line.
```

The resulting output looks like:

```
Test Customer 28.06.2019
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 79
This section starts with 10 blanks right alignment
---------1. Test Nr. 1
2. Test Nr. 2
--------------------
Section starts with 5 blanks ...
This is the last line.
```

Can anyone help to understand why the blanks are not shown in the resulting PDF?

Regards,

Ralf

Hi mkl,

Thanks for reponding. I have added the following code and it looks much better in regard to the spaces :-)

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replace("\u0020", "\u00A0");
            document.add(new Paragraph(line).setFont(normal));
        }
```

The only problem I have are the CR after each line. Do you have an idea why a have an extra line after each line?

Regards,

Ralf

## UPDATE

I have added a `System.out.println(line);` before the document.add code and the resulting output doesn't show any extra line:

```
Test Customer                                                         28.06.2019
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         10        20        30        40        50        60        70       79
         This section starts with 10 blanks                      right alignment
---------1. Test Nr. 1
         2. Test Nr. 2         
--------------------
    Section starts with 5 blanks ...
This is the last line.
```

Note: If I use `System.out.print(line);` I get only one line - no \n.

Seems to be that the iText document.add will generate these extra line(s) !!??

Regards,

Ralf

Comment: Try and replace the space characters (0x20) by non-breaking space characters (0xA0).

Comment: works fine as mentioned above (line = line.replace("\u0020", "\u00A0");). Do you have an idea why I have an extra line after each line?

Comment: Is it possible that those "extra lines" are not actually independent lines but instead large leading values for the paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code to:

```
public void createPdf(File sourceFile, String dest) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        document.setFontSize((float) 8.0);
        document.setLeftMargin((float) 40.0);
        document.setRightMargin((float) 40.0);

        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(sourceFile), "UTF8"));
        String line;
        PdfFont normal = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.setFont(normal);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replace("\u0020", "\u00A0");
            para.add(line + "\n");
            //document.add(new Paragraph(line).setFont(normal));    
        }
        document.add(para);
        document.close();
        br.close();
    }
```

and now it looks as expected. I think it's related to "document.add(new Paragraph) ..." in the wile loop, which seems to be add a NL for each new paragraph.

Regards,

Ralf

Comment: *"which seems to be add a NL for each new paragraph"* - No, but commonly (at least in one common layout style) there is a bit of extra space between paragraphs. If you add each of your lines as a separate paragraph, therefore, you'll get that extra space. If on the other hand you add a single paragraph containing all of your lines, you don't get that extra space between your lines.

Comment: mkl - Thanks a lot for your explanation - that makes sense and explains the behavior. As you suggested, adding the lines to a single paragraph and than adding this paragraph solves my problems.

Comment: Good; then you should eventually accept your own answer (click the tick at the answer's upper left, under the voting arrows) to mark the question as resolved.